# Letter is in an Element of an Array

Tags: java, arrays, string

How do I see if an Element of an array of Strings contains a certain letter? I need it for hangman. Array of words used is Words. continueGame() is where I am putting this. I thought that I could get my random word, then find out if the letter is in that random word. How do I do that?

```
  public void continueGame(){
    letterSelected = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Take another guess!");

        if(getWords().indexOf(getWords()) == (letterSelected)){

        }

        if(! getWords().contains(letterSelected)){
         guesses++;
         continueGame();
        }else{
           System.out.println(letterSelected);
        }
    checkBodyParts();
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "");
}
```

#

```
/**Get the random word from the array*/
public String getWords (){
    String randomWord = words[randy.nextInt( words.length)];
    return randomWord;
}



/**Get the indexes of the letter of the random word indices don't start with 1*/
public String getSelected(){
    return letterSelected;
}

/**Finds index of the letter of randomWord*/
public int getIndex(){
    int index = getWords().indexOf(getSelected());
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the snippet you gave us.

But you can consider the following code to find word of an `Array` that contains a specified character :

```
String[] words = {"foo", "bar", "qux"};
for (String word : words)
{
    if (word.indexOf('a') != -1)
    {
        System.out.println("Matched word '" + word + "' for character 'a'");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just don't get your logic. You are returning new random word everytime you call getWords().
You should assign randomly generated word to some variable and then work with this variable.

To your concrete problem it should be something like this:

```
// get your random word
String myGeneratedRandomWord = getWords ();

// your method 
public void continueGame(){
   letterSelected = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Take another guess!");
   if(myGeneratedRandomWord.indexOf(letterSelected ) != -1) {
        // it contains the letter
   }
   else {
        // wrong guess
   }
}
```

Read more about [String.indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) method.

Comment: @user1972601 well and did it actually help you ? As a new user here on StackOverflow I advise you to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). Thanks